# Posting string from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

First of all, thank you in advance for any help you can give. I am currently trying to connect my android application to a mysql database (Xampp). Below is the code that I am using in Android

```
public void submitRecipe(View view) throws IOException
    {
    URL u = new URL("http://localhost/phpconnect.php");
    String data  = "recipe="+"mar";
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(); 
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

After wr.write(data), the application always crashes. I know that I am not posting any meaningful information with this small code segment, but I am just trying to get it to work right now. Php code is below. Thank you in advance for any help you can give as I am new to Android and am just trying to get my connection to my database to work.

```
    <?php
    if(empty($_POST['recipe'])
{
    echo "BAD";
}
else
{
    $alpha = "recipe";

    // Try to connect to the database.
    $database=mysqli_connect("localhost","Michael","12345");
    mysqli_select_db($database,"customers");

    // If failed
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      // The database cannot be connected to.
      echo "Database could not be connected to";
      return;
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($database,"Select * From recipes Where Url LIKE '%" + $alpha + "%'");

    if($query==FALSE)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $output[]=$row;
        }
        echo "GOOD";
        mysqli_close($database);
    }
}

?>
```

08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001): Process: com.example.websiteapp, PID: 5001
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     ... 11 more
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.example.websiteapp.RecipePage.submitRecipe(RecipePage.java:94)
08-14 22:10:44.553: E/AndroidRuntime(5001):     ... 14 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash has nothing to do with the server side code -- you're trying to execute a network call on the main (UI) thread, thus the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Try running it inside an AsyncTask's doInBackground.